# Using scanf & strcmp and get exact pattern, is it possible?

Tags: c

I was asked following interesting question in one of the interview which I couldnt answer because I explained

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_passwd()
{
    unsigned int check = 0;
    unsigned char passwd[6];

    scanf("%s", passwd);
    if (strcmp(passwd, "secret") == 0)
        check = 1;
    return check;
}

int main()
{
    if (check_passwd())
        printf("Password correct\n");
    else
        printf("Password is incorrect\n");
    return 0;
}
```

His question was "Can you hack your input so that you will hit "Password Correct" without knowing the strmcp is looking for "secret" in passwd array"

I tried explaining to the interviewer about pit falls of scanf and stack thrashing it can occur here, but he was not convinced.

Anyways I too was convinced that I couldnt answer but would love to know if its possible to hit true case without knowing the pattern?

Comment: `char passwd[6];` is too small to accept the password `"secret"`. The code has undefined behaviour, allowing as you do, buffer overflow. Please don't be so tight with your user input buffers, and protect them, e.g. with `scanf("%5s", passwd);`. They don't cost you money.

Comment: The interviewer is **wrongly** assuming that the variable `check` is immediately after the array. So your task is simply to enter any seven-letter string. A six-letter string will dump the zero byte into `check`, which leaves `check` with its initial value of 0. A string shorter than six letters has no effect on `check`. And a string longer than seven letters risks causing a crash.

Comment: There is no guarantee what the buffer overflow will corrupt. It is the compiler's choice how to sequence the variable declarations.

Comment: IMJO, a poor interview question.

Comment: With naive memory layout, 7 characters should be enough if the system is byte aligned. If word aligned, there will be 2 or 6 byte padding, so you'll also need characters to fill that. An optimising compiler will notice check is unchanged between where it's set and returned, and replace it with a return constant, ditching the check variable altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, but not guaranteed.  For this to work, `check` needs to appear just after `passwd` in memory.

Assuming this is the case, passing a string larger than 5 characters when prompted will cause `scanf` to write all of the bytes of `passwd` then past that into the bytes of `check`.  Inputting a string of more than characters will result in at least one byte of `check` being non-zero.  This non-zero value will then be returned from the function, causing the `if` statement to follow the "true" branch and print "Password Correct".

If the string entered is long enough to extend into the return address for `check_passwd`, the code will most likely crash.

Comment: @user3386109 Right, that should have bee "more than 6".  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

> The interviewer is wrongly assuming that the variable check is
> immediately after the array. So your task is simply to enter any
> seven-letter string. A six-letter string will dump the zero byte into
> check, which leaves check with its initial value of 0. A string
> shorter than six letters has no effect on check. And a string longer
> than seven letters risks causing a crash. -
> @user3386109

```
./hack              
hello1b    
Password correct
```

However, this is not guaranteed since `check` might not be located right after `passwd`.

On on the other hand, if we run the program under the `strings` utility:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc.so.6
__isoc99_scanf
printf
strcmp
__libc_start_main
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.2.5
__gmon_start__
secret              ---> Here's the password. 
Password correct
Password is incorrect
;*3$"
```

Comment: I do understand stack allocation and orientation, but linux environment would'nt allow stack smashing. I tried myself to push what your saying here and end up with ```*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really poor interview question. In order to exploit this code, you would need to know CPU ISA. Does it have an up-counting or down-counting SP? OS, if applicable? Stack frame format and calling convention.? Also when hacking something you aren't given the source code in C. Even if you have it you would have to know which compiler and optimization level that was used... What if `check` is allocated in a register as per the calling convention?

- Also the C source will not even compile since you cannot implicitly convert an `unsigned char*` to the `char*` that `strcmp` expects. Parameters passed to functions are done so "as per the rules of assignment" and assigning an `unsigned char*` to a `char*` is not a valid form of assignment.
- Also the buffer `passwd` cannot hold the string `"secret"` because it's too small. So this program that you are supposed to "exploit" probably never worked during normal use to begin with.
- Also empty parenthesis after functions has been obsolescent style since the ancient dinosaur days.

Answer: this C program cannot be exploited because the program cannot be built with a conforming C compiler.

Comment: I agree with you, these are mostly interviewers trying to showoff their extra smartness but then you dont want to argue with them.  The initial code which he showed had lot of syntax issues, I told him to correct them and also explained him scanf's are not supposed to be used without boundary checks and if its I/O via scanf then it will lead to bugs & stack smashing or segmentation issues. Anyways just left him there and walked out of interview.